# choosing best 100 players from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ive got table with columns:

```
PlayerId
Points
```

I would like to get 100 best players (the more points player have, the better he is). What would be the quesry for that ?

Im using sql server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when two or more players have the same points?, or even worse, what happens if you have 120 players with the maximum points. You should use a query that returns every one of those players. I recommend that you use `RANK` if this is the case.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Points DESC) RN
    FROM Players
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 100
```

Comment: @AleTiro - Well, It might be if all op wants are the top 100 players. But what to do when players have the same points?, if that is the case, then I believe that `RANK` is the better way to do it. Furthermore, if op would want the players that have the top 100 points, then s/he should use `DENSE_RANK`

Comment: maybe you're right, maybe he was looking for a more precise way to do it... I might be doing it wrong, but I don't ask anything here before I look through the whole internets/msdn/SO...

Comment: this describes the problem that I wanted to appear during the discussion, thank You very much for this hint

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TOP 100 PlayerId
FROM TableName
ORDER BY Points DESC
```

To break it down:

- `TOP 100` - Selects the top 100 records to return.
- `ORDER BY Points DESC` - Orders the results by the `Points` field, and `DESC` sets them in numerical reverse (assuming `Points` is an integer data type).

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to select the top X from the query and then order by the points in descending order.

```
select top 100 * from players order by Points DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 100 PlayerID 
FROM <<Table>> 
ORDER BY Points DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is `Players`:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PlayerId, Points
FROM Players
ORDER BY Points DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 100 PlayerId FROM name_of_your_table ORDER BY Points DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM tblName ORDER BY Points DESC
```